# format error in python string to time conversion

Tags: python

When I try to display the string in time, I get a format error.

```
result3 = ''.join(file_name)


date_time_str = result3

result1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')





print(result1)
```

The problem here is that ValueError:time data 20220308233355'does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S' error occurs. Did I enter the wrong format? I want to mark 20220308233355 as yyyy-mm--dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: The format string contains dashes `-`, a space, and colons `:`.  But your data string does not contain those.  So it does not match.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you wanna do this:

```
result1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(result1)
```

```
>> 2022-03-08 23:33:55
```

which is datetime type , if you want string in that format , you have to :

```
result1 = result1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```